# How to detect file/folder moves from change list in Google Drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, google-drive-api

I am writing a application that sync local file hierarchy with **Google Drive**. Am using [Objecive-C client APIs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/). To keep the local hierarchy in sync am using [Changes list API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list). The changes list returned by the above API is not in chronological order in the following scenario:

1. Create folder 'Vehichle' in Google Drive.
2. Create folder 'Car' inside 'Vehichle' folder.
3. Create folder 'Personal Doc' inside 'Vehichle' folder.
4. Create file "Insurance.txt" inside fodler 'Car'.
5. Move file "Insurance.txt" from folder 'Car' to 'Personal Doc'.

In the above scenario changes related to 'Personal Doc' folder is at the end of changes list. It is expected to come before changes related to "Insurance.txt". Why is this behaviour? Is it ignored to optimize the change list. If so, is there way to include all operations?

Comment: Couldnt you just sort it after yourself by modifiedDate?

Comment: @DaImTo can't determine using modifiedDate. Is it bug in API.